# An unobvious behavior of collect() method

Tags: swift, combine

```
private lazy var dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(
        label: "\(type(of: self))",
        attributes: .concurrent
    )

func makeArrayGreatAgain(elem0: SomeStruct, elem1: SomeStruct, elem2: SomeStruct, elem3: SomeStruct) {
[elem0 elem1, elem2, elem3]
.publisher
.receive(on: dispatchQueue)
.tryMap { print("R", $0) } // Void
.eraseToAnyPublisher() // just copy-pasted
.collect(4)
.sink { result in print("E", result) }
 receiveValue: { result in print("S", result) }
}
```

from time to time I see different logs.

For example:

```
R
R
R
S [(), (), ()]
E
R
```

or

```
R
R
R
R
S [(), (), (), ()]
E
```

Why? I want to obtain the whole result:

```
    R
    R
    R
    R
    S [(), (), (), ()]
    E
```

How can I achieve this?

***Comment***

the same problem appears for `collect()` without arguments

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `.collect()` and everything to do with `receive(on:)` that receives, in your example, on a **concurrent** queue.

So, the values and - crucially for this question - the completion signal, are processed concurrently, so the order they are emitted in is not the same as the order they arrived in.

And so, sometimes, the completion signal actually arrives at the next step before all the values had arrived.

If the next step is a `collect` publisher, when it sees the completion, it emits an array of values that it received up to that point and also completes.

---

To ensure that you receive the values in order, use a serial queue:

```
var serialQ = DispatchQueue(
    label: "foo"
)

let c = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
   .publisher
   .receive(on: serialQ) // or receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
   .map { print("R", $0) }
   .collect()
   .sink (receiveCompletion: { print("E", $0) },
          receiveValue: { print("S", $0) })
```

You will always get:

```
R 1
R 2
R 3
R 4
S [(),(),(),()]
E finished
```